# JCodeModel and elseif

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I'm generating Java source code with JCodeModel and want to get an "if-elseif" block like this:

```
 if (foo){

 } else if (bar) {

 }
```

As far as I understand the according code would be something like this (where *m* is a JMethod):

```
JConditional cond = m.body()._if(JExpr.direct("foo"));
cond._elseif(JExpr.direct("bar"));
```

Seems to be straight forward, but the result is this:

```
if (foo) {
    } else {
        if (bar) {
        }
    }
```

You see the syntactic difference, it's not actually an "elseif". Semantically it's the same, I know, but I need it to be generated as shown before (it's part of educational software). Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not do this using `JConditional` because of its implementation. Have a look at the source of the method `_elseif`:

```
 public JConditional _elseif(JExpression boolExp) {
     return _else()._if(boolExp);
 }
```

As you can see, this method just invoke `_else()` and then `_if` internally.

Actually `_else()` is `JBlock` which contains `braces` (`{ ... }`) by default. This property of `JBlock` can **not** be switched off manually because it doesn't contain such setter. `braces` could be switched off only through special constructor of `JBlock`:

```
 public JBlock(boolean bracesRequired, boolean indentRequired) {
     this.bracesRequired = bracesRequired;
     this.indentRequired = indentRequired;
 }
```

but you are not able to set you own object to `_else` field of `JConditional` object outwardly.

The only way is copy `JConditional` class implementation and generate your own, which will allow you such code manipulation.

**UPD:** Of course you can always use `Reflection` as workaround for manually switching flag `bracesRequired` of `_else` object to `false`.